# JavaScript hardware access

Tags: javascript

I know difference between browser Js and NodeJS. I'm looking at this trezor.io bitcoin hardware wallet. How are they managing to send information from their drive to javascript on website only trough USB port ? (device has no WiFi or Bluetooth) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By requiring that you install an application on the computer.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It's a Chrome extension, using [`chrome.usb`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb).

This is the leading edge of the [WebUSB stuff](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/), which will allow JavaScript in browsers to access USB devices. (Obviously there's some security stuff that's having to be worked through...)